# search a number in an unsorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I have a code that searches for a given entry in an array, and returns the position in the array of that entry, provided one knows the array contain that number. However, a strange thing happens. When I try to test the code with some concrete arrays, the code works well for some entries, and it does not work for others. The code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int Find_entry(int data[], int n, int x)
{
    int a = (n/2);
    int b = n;
    int tmp = 0;

    while (x != data[a])
    {
        if (x > data[a])
        {
            tmp = a;
            a = (b+a)/2;
            b = b;
        }
        if (x < data[a])
        {
            a = tmp;
            b = a;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

(in a previous version I was using the floor function to round the numbers contained in a to their integer parts, but I understand this is not necessary.)

I have tested the program for example for the following array in this main:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 6; int x = 12;
    int array1[] = {3,12,5,9,7,11};
    cout << "The entry " << x << " is found at position " 
         << 1+Find_entry(array1, n, x) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I type as in this example x=12, the program gives the correct answer 1. Same thing for x=3, x=11 and x=9. But if I type x=7 or x=5, the program refuses to give an output and I get a message like

"Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 9 second(s))".

Can anybody explain what's the problem here? How can be the code fixed?? Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: The answer is in the question title - it is unsorted.

Comment: `while (x != data[a])` is certainly wrong (if x does not exist)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use binary search for unsorted array. Use linear search.

```
int Find_entry(int data[], int n, int x)
{
    int a = 0;

    while (a < n && x != data[a]) a++;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: You can use binary search on ANY array it just isn't efficient on an unsorted one.  You should know better.

Comment: @RandomGuy You have significantly misunderstood binary search. The whole purpose is that you make use of the structure that comes from knowing the data is sorted, to do a faster search. That's how you know whether to look left or right at a given step.

Comment: Nope, I take that back.  I'm suffering from an insufficient coffee error.  Please ignore me until the caffeine kicks in.

Comment: @BobtFish, I don't even know what binary search is. I have just tried to make an algorithm to find an entry in an array that does not require the array to be sorted in increasing order. Just wondering why for some entries of the arrays it gives the correct result, but for others it fails. I don't understand your answer.

Comment: @RandomGuy What you have written looks like an attempt on an algorithm called binary search, which is why everyone is mentioning it. They assumed that is what you intended, since it is well known. And it doesn't work on unsorted input.

Comment: @RandomGuy Quick answer -- luck.  You are lucky that the numbers you chose for the (ahem) "working" examples were set up in a way that the binary search didn't fall flat on its face.  No different than when an experiment seems like it would work, and then all sorts of counter-examples exists where it doesn't.  If indeed your technique worked, and you found an element in logarithmic time for an unsorted array, you would be hailed as the next Knuth.

Comment: @RandomGuy Have you used the debugger to show you the flow of your program when you choose a value that doesn't work?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no, I am quite new to all this and I don't know how to use a debugger. Of course I am prone to make stupid mistakes. I understand that this procedure is flawed and I see that in fact it makes use of the sorting of the array contrary to what I claimed before. I will try to see if this code can at least be converted to a working code for a sorted array, that should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search only works on sorted inputs.

Comment: Of course it does.  It simply loses it's efficiency.

Comment: @soulsabr it's worth than that: looking for 0 in `{ 1 ; 0 ; 1 }` gives no result since both upper bound and lower bound are strictly greater than the *searchee*.

Comment: Actually, we're both wrong and right.  I'm looking at his/her algorithm and addressing it as if it were a binary search.  You're calling it a binary search.  It isn't a binary search making us both wrong.  :)  His algorithm will work as is but he needs to fix the rounding error.

Comment: @soulsabr prove in with an MCVE. I can tell a binary search when I see one. And this is (a buggy one, but it kind of is) :)

Comment: See my comment above about lack of coffee and ignoring me right now.

Comment: @RandomGuy think about how your code would work if searching for `99` in the array `{99, 0, 0, 0}`.